# More efficient way of modifying selected elements in an array of json using Underscore.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, underscore.js

In JavaScript, I have the following array of json objects and I would like to change those ticked with 'false' to 'true'. I am currently using the `_.map()` function in Underscore.js, is there a more efficient way of selecting the 'false' elements and only modify them?

```
var arrOfJson = [
 {"name" : "Tom", "ticked" : false},
 {"name" : "John", "ticked" : true},
 {"name" : "Patrick", "ticked" : false},
 {"name" : "Dave", "ticked" : true}
];


_.map(arrOfJson, function(entry){
   entry.ticked = false;
   return entry;
});
```

Comment: If efficiency is a major concern, I'd recommend a plain old `for` loop.

Comment: efficiency is not a concern at all, I am just trying to see if there's a better way. thanks

Comment: Then perhaps you should clarify your question a bit. I'd say `_.map` is fine, but I think `_.each` is more understandable, semantically, and you can get rid of the `return` line. The performance would be nominal either way.

Comment: Map is used to transform items in a list into something else. To update items in a list just iterate over the list and change the value accordingly. To iterate use a good old for loop or something like _.each in underscore.

Answer (score 0):

Thats pretty efficient. Im the author of open source project http://www.jinqJs.com. You could do something like this using javaScript LINQ expression

```
var result = jinqJs().from(arrOfJson).select([{field: 'name'}, {text:'ticked', value: true}]);
```